# How to find the last three files added in a directory

Tags: python

I'm using this code to find the last csv file added but I'm not able to find the last 3 files added. I can eliminate the last file and then find the max again but I think it'd be too long. Can you please help me find a solution? All I need is to find the last 3 csv files added in a directory.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
import zipfile

t=[]

j_csvs="path2"

#Find all csv files directories and collect them within t
d = os.path.join(j_csvs)
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(d):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            p=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
            t.append(p)
        else: "DoNothing"

latest_f_j = max(t, key=os.path.getctime)      
df=pd.read_csv(latest_f_j)
df
```

Comment: Consider using `Path('my_file.mp3').suffix == '.mp3'` instead of `file.endswith(".csv")` as it is more robust. You can import `Path` by `from pathlib import Path`.

Comment: use `sorted` instead of `max` and then slice

Comment: After sorting as @cards suggested, you can easily target the `n` latest.

Comment: @RovshanAliyev : as suggested by *@cards* just use: `latest_f_j = sorted(t, key=os.path.getctime); df=pd.read_csv(latest_f_j[-3:])`

Comment: @cards, I used your suggestion and it works. Thanks! The code: latest_f_j = sorted(t, key=os.path.getctime)  
latest_csvs = latest_f_j[-3:]
df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in latest_csvs:
    table=pd.read_csv(i)
    df=pd.concat([df,table])

Answer (score 1):

Use `sorted` with a callback function to infer the ordering relationship, some possibilities:

- with `os.path.getctime` for system’s ctime (it is system dependent, see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html))
- with `os.path.getmtime` for the time of last modification
- with `os.path.getatime` for the time of last access.

Pass the `reverse=True` parameter for a result in descending order and then slice.

```
import os.path

def last_newest_files(path, ref_ext='csv', amount=3):
    # return files ordered by newest to oldest

    def f_conditions(path):
        # check by file and extension
        _, ext = os.path.splitext(path) # ext start with ".", ie ".csv"
        return os.path.isfile(path) and ext.lstrip('.') == ref_ext

    # apply conditions
    filtered_files = filter(f_conditions, (os.path.join(path, basename) for basename in os.listdir(path)))

    # get the newest
    return sorted(filtered_files, key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)[:amount]


path_dir = '.'
ext = 'csv'
last_n_files = 3

print(*last_newest_files(path_dir, ext, last_n_files), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot determine what the last 3 files added are with any degree of certainty.

At the upper level, a system may put those file in order of date, file type, size, name - both case sensitive and without.

With date order, you have no way of knowing since date stamps can be manipulated, as can pre-dated files moved into a directory and thus preserving its original date and time details.

If you are looking at files at a lower level, as that seen by the file system, then they are generally unordered. The o/s on its own whim, will store the details as it sees fit.

You have no way whatsoever in determining which of 3 files were the last to added. Well, you have one way, run a watch on the directory which will fire when a file is added and keep a circular list of 3 replacing the current before moving onto the next and then waiting for the next trigger to fire.

Comment: They're all brand new files that just created. All I need is which ones are the last three created/added/modified.

Comment: Then it's by date ordered? I assume you will have looked at file file being started  and another starting and ending before the previous has finished? Good luck on determining which was the last in that scenario.

Comment: They're csv files that coming to the folder on daily basis. Every day one csv file is added to the folder by system

Comment: @RovshanAliyev : as already suggested in the comments to your question by *cards* just use: `latest_f_j = sorted(t, key=os.path.getctime); df=pd.read_csv(latest_f_j[-3:])`